# Leaflet var to php

Tags: leaflet, php, post

I have a function when I click on the marker:

```
function onMarkerClick (e) {
         id1 = "something";
         $ .post ("content.php", {id_a: id1}, function (result) {
             alert (result);
     });
}
```

The function works when I click the marker, but I get nothing from the content.php page

Comment: To get de var in php I use:
`code`$id_x=$_REQUEST["id_a"];
echo $id_a;
`code`

But I get nothing.
Thanks

Comment: You should ask this question on https://stackoverflow.com/.